# Reading SQL Server database using datasource

Tags: asp.net

I have created a datasource to connect with SQL Server database. It works fine when I connected it with GridView. I need to read certain item (say `FirstName`) and store the value to a variable.

How can I use this datasource? Could you give me the statements for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SqlDataSource` is intended as what the name implies - a data source for data binding. It is **not** a way to get individual values from a database table.

If you need to read a single value, you should use straight ADO.NET - `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` - to read that value - something like:

```
string sqlStmt = "SELECT FirstName FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = @ID";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(your-connection-string-here-))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4044;

   conn.Open();
   string firstName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
   conn.Close();
}
```

The `ExecuteScalar` call works only if you want to read a single row, single column value - like here. Otherwise you need to use either the `SqlDataReader`, or use the `DataTable` and a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill that data table (if you have multiple rows).

**Update:** if you want to use a `SqlDataAdapter` instead - do this:

```
public DataTable LoadData()
{
   DataTable result = new DataTable();

   string sqlStmt = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Country " + 
                    "FROM dbo.YourTable";

   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(your-connection-string-here-))
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
   {
       SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       dap.Fill(result);
   }

   return result;
}
```

When you call this method, you'll get back a `DataTable` that contains the columns you've defined in your SQL statement, and all rows from the database table.

```
DataTable myData = LoadData();
```

Now, you can iterate over the rows and get the `FirstName` value for each row:

```
foreach(DataRow row in myData.Rows)
{
     string firstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
     // do whatever you need to do with the first name
}
```

Comment: Is something like ds.Tables["tablename"].Rows[rownumber]["columnname"] possible?  Even this did not work but someone recommended it to me.

Comment: @furqan sehgal: if you use a `SqlDataAdapter` and fill a `DataTable` - yes! With a `SqlDataSource` - no.

Comment: Please advise how to add sqlDataAdapter and Datatable and how to bind them.  Is there somehting like binding source we have in winforms.  Also please give statement that I would need to do my required operation.

Comment: @furqan sehgal: updated my response - what do you need to do with the "FirstName" value(s) after you've loaded it??